# Why my Selenium test code run successfully in single-step but failed when using Run?

Tags: java, debugging, firefox, testing, selenium

I have some Selenium code which do some automatic UI tests using Firefox driver. I bind them into a test suite and run them orderly. But it fails on a **driver.switchTo().frame()** invocation and throws a **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame**, the full error messages are as below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: OpenNewPKFD
Command duration or timeout: 3.07 seconds
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'H3000-0254', ip: '169.254.169.127', os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_13'
Session ID: 4fcea4bb-880c-4725-bdf1-cda4b5a03553
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=32.0.3, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

The weird thing is, if I run it in single-step mode, the code line which throws above exception will work just fine. No error occurs. So I suspect there're something related to time or speed, but I don't know what it is at all.

So can you give me some advice to deal with this problem?

***UPDATED*** below is my pom.xml of the project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>GALSelenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>GALSelenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <selenium.version>2.43.1</selenium.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: How are you finding the `<iframe>` element? Are you using an ExpectedCondition to ensure that it is loaded into the DOM when you try and switch to it?

Comment: @MarkRowlands Seems not, would you please offer me some tutorial or example links about this?

Comment: Take a look at the docs, http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html, and below is a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the ExpectedConditions, ensure that you have imported them into your project

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions

Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//to wait for an element you need a webdriverWait object
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenseOfElementLocated(By.ID("your_id"));
```

As such for you issue, I would imagine something like:

```
frameToSwitchTo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenseOfElementLocated(By.ID("OpenNewPKFD"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameToSwitchTo);
```